# Filter pandas dataframe from tuples

Tags: python, pandas

```
AB_col = [(0,230), (10,215), (15, 200), (20, 185), (40, 177), 
                (0,237), (10,222), (15, 207), (20, 192), (40, 184)]

sales = [{'account': 'Jones LLC', 'A': 0, 'B': 230, 'C': 140},
         {'account': 'Alpha Co',  'A': 20, 'B': 192, 'C': 215},
         {'account': 'Blue Inc',  'A': 50,  'B': 90,  'C': 95 }]
df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
print df
```

> > **result**
> >     [image: df]

Now the above dataframe has to be filtered by the AB_col list of tuples. I tried something like

```
df[df["A","B"].zip.isin(AB_col)]
```

But it did not work, How to filter the above dataframe to the one like below

[image: dfexpected]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need create `Series` of `tuples`:

```
df = df[df[["A","B"]].apply(tuple, 1).isin(AB_col)]
```

Alternative:

```
df = df[pd.Series(list(zip(df.A, df.B)), index=df.index).isin(AB_col)]
```

Or you can compare `MultiIndex` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df[df.set_index(['A','B']).index.isin(AB_col)]
```

Or create your own MultiIndex and filter:

```
df = df[pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df['A'], df['B']]).isin(AB_col)]
```

---

```
print (df)
    A    B    C    account
0   0  230  140  Jones LLC
1  20  192  215   Alpha Co
```

Comment: FWIW, the first solution seems to be an order of magnitude slower than the alternatives.  The multiindex seems to be the fastest, followed by the zip, but being not much slower I’d consider using the `set_index` method for the sake of readability, unless speed is a critical issue.